# how to list dataframes with characteres between patterns

Tags: r, list, file, dataframe, pattern-matching

How do we list files which has letters between patterns in their names?
Lets say we have several dataframes like AgI_M.txt, AgI_PQ.txt, AgII_M.txt, AgII_PQ.txt, AgIII_M.txt, AgIII_PQ.txt, AgN_M.txt, AgN_PQ.txt, CoI_M.txt, CoI_PQ.txt, CoN_M.txt, CoN_PQ.txt, .... 
And we want to make a list with those who start with "Ag" and ends with "_M.txt".
I need to know what do we put in the middle of the pattern definition please.
Until now i guess it should be something like

```
Ag_files<-list.files(path="",
                     pattern="Ag\\ \\_M.txt") #what do we do put in the middle?
```

Than... Do i name them (dataframes in the list) using their original names like this?

```
Ag_data<-lapply(Ag_files, read.table)
names(Ag_data)<-gsub(""Ag\\ \\_M.txt"","", Ag_files)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pattern :

```
Ag_files <- list.files(path, pattern="^Ag.*_M\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE)
```

then read the data in a list

```
Ag_data <- lapply(Ag_files, read.table)
```

and name the list.

```
names(Ag_data)<- sub("_M","", basename(Ag_files))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak!! First, thanks again! It works great until we name them. I've tried 1) leaving the ```x``` argument on ```sub``` as ```" "``` to call original names; 2) in the same argument write some kind of pattern as the one used to find the tables; and 3) specify ```replacement = FALSE```.... but it is giving the path names for those files as names ... e.g. instead of giving back the name AgI_M.txt to the corresponding one, it receive the name "C:/users/....AgI_M.txt"... what do we do? thanks!

Comment: @CristóbalJarabaNilo Can you share output of `head(basename(Ag_files))` ?

Comment: Oh well, it is ```[1] "AgIX_M.txt"  "AgXIV_M.txt"```

Comment: @CristóbalJarabaNilo oopps it should be `basename(Ag_files)`. I missed that. Can you check the updated answer ?

Comment: same output on console: ```[1] "AgIX_M.txt"  "AgXIV_M.txt"``` . Can you check a new question i made here https://stackoverflow.com/q/59403498/12542568 please. Since you start helping me i have done nice things, so now im in the more ugly part. Thanks again!

Comment: For this question, this gives you a named list right in `Ag_data` ? Is that what you are expecting or something else ?

Comment: this problem is related to the other question, i mean, im trying to run the MDS function to smaller lists with same groups definitions as an alternative of the issue of not being able to run it over a list with dataframe with different groups definitions. But naming ```Ag_data``` with ```names(Ag_data)<- sub("^Ag(.*)_M\\.txt$","\\1", basename(Ag_files))``` didnt work well because outputs are not getting the name of the original dataframe as i wanted so infer they are not named correctly.

Comment: elements on ```Ag_data``` gets names as ```[[1]]``` and ```[[2]]``` and not the same as the original element. I expect to list files with the pattern you help me define and than name them with the same name with one more letter behind to difference them from the original... or simply name them as their original name instead ```[[1]]```, ```[[2]]``` or ```"C:/users/....AgI_M.txt"```

Comment: What output do you get for `sub("^Ag(.*)_M\\.txt$","\\1", basename(Ag_files))` ? For the example shared, (`[1] "AgIX_M.txt" "AgXIV_M.txt"`) running `sub("^Ag(.*)_M\\.txt$","\\1", basename(Ag_files))` returns `[1] "IX"  "XIV"` is that what you need as names ? If not then what would you need ?
`

Comment: Oh wow! well, thats much better! I expect to name them as they were without the "_M" at the end. That is "AgIX.txt" for "AgIX_M.txt" and "AgXIV.txt" for "AgXIV_M.txt" . Thanks Ronak!!

Comment: In that case, use `names(Ag_data)<- sub("_M","", basename(Ag_files))`

Comment: Oh, sorry, i didnt answer your question, Im getting the same output you write here. That is, ```[1] "IX" "XIV"``` when run ```basename(Ag_file)``` on console and "IX" and "XIV" as names when pin the list ```Ag_data``` in the environment/Data window.

Comment: ```names(Ag_data)<- sub("_M","", basename(Ag_files))``` was the solution to this. I can run my MDS function to this smaller list with common factor groups. THANKS ONCE AGAIN RONAK! Now i would like to know if its possible to run the MDS function through a list of data frames with different factor groups. Thanks!!!